# Center a div that is inline-block

Tags: css, html, centering

I have a .container div that I want to center on the page.

Unfortunately, the div is supposed to fit the table that is in inside. So if the table is at 75% of the page, I want the `.container` to be at 75% as well.

My .container looks like this:

```
.container{
  display:inline-block;
  background:#FFF;
  height:500px;
  max-width:80%;
}
```

I made a JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Dey7W/).

Thanks for all help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to center an inline-block element and if so, how?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7601678/is-it-possible-to-center-an-inline-block-element-and-if-so-how)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `text-align:center` to the parent of an `inline-block` element will center it.

[**Updated jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Dey7W/1/)

In this case, it would be:

```
body {
    text-align:center;
}
```