# Aligning inline-block center

Tags: html, center, centering, css

What would be the easiest way to center align an inline-block element?

Ideally, I don't want to set a width to the elements. This way depending on the text inputted within the elements, the inline-block element will expand to the new width without having to change the width within the CSS. The inline-block elements should be centered on top of one another (not side by side), as well as the text within the element.

See code below or see on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwierzba/bcL023ko/).

The current HTML:

```
<div>
  <h2>Hello, John Doe.</h2>
  <h2>Welcome and have a wonderful day.</h2>
</div>
```

The current SCSS:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600);  

body {
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: rgba(51,51,51,1);
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

div {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 15% 0;
    text-align: center;
    h2 {
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 10px;
        text-align: center;
        float: left;
        clear: left;
        display: inline-block;
        &:first-child {
            color: black;
            background: rgba(255,255,255,1);
        }
        &:last-child {
            color: white;
            background: rgba(117,80,161,1);
        }
    }
}
```

Adding a br between the two elements and taking out the float: left/clear: left may be the easiest way; however, I was curious if there was another way going about this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to center an inline-block element and if so, how?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7601678/is-it-possible-to-center-an-inline-block-element-and-if-so-how)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/bcL023ko/3/
Remove the `float:left` left and add `margin: 0 auto` to center the element. Or is it something else that your are looking for?

Comment: You don't need to use the `margin:0 auto` if the parent has `text-align:center` with `inline-block` elements - http://jsfiddle.net/bcL023ko/4/

Comment: @k-nut I am looking for the elements to be stacked on top of each other, not side by side.

Comment: @k-nut I am looking for the elements to be stacked on top of each other.

Comment: What browser and resolution are you using? They are stacked for me.

Comment: @k-nut I see that they stack at smaller resolutions, but not at all sizes. I am using chrome and my screen resolution is 1920x1080.

Comment: @Andrew if you wrap your h2s with 100% width containers you should be able to solve your problems. I had to introduce some classes for this, I am sure that there is a more elegant solution http://jsfiddle.net/bcL023ko/6/

Comment: @k-nut Awesome! I will give that a try.