# how to center inline-block element?

Tags: css, alignment, center

This is not a duplicate as far as I can tell. The other cases don't answer my question because they only address centering an element, they don't have a block next to it (thus the "text-align: center" on a parent element won't help).

I have two text elements side by side, but I want one to be centered on the page **and the other right next to it**. The kicker is that the centered text is dynamic because it plugs in the user's name. So, I don't know how wide the text in the div is going to be.

If I make the text div inline-block or float: left it won't center. **If I put both text divs into a container with text-align:** center it will center both of them.

I just want one centered and the other next to it. Is such a thing possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7601678/is-it-possible-to-center-an-inline-block-element-and-if-so-how  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980525/css-center-display-inline-block

Comment: As I stated in the original question, the two elements need to be side by side, one centered and one not. Therefore, using align: center on a parent element won't work.

Comment: Without seeing the HTML structure you propose using ut's hard to even have this re-opened. A child div could be positioned in relation to a centered parent but a sibling is much more problematical.

Comment: As the question concerns adjacent elements relative to a centred element, this may not be a duplicate.