# Align circles in the center on mobiles

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm trying to align circles in the center on mobile. Here is what I've used on https://www.wmhi.com.au/elite-edge-leadership-resilience/

```
.circle {
  width: 240px;
  height: 240px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #ea4335;
  vertical-align: top; 
  display: inline-block;

}
.circle:hover {
background-color:#79c852;
color:white;
}
```

I need to keep the texts as laid there now (inline-block). The circles are appearing left aligned on mobile phones. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Because your circles are `inline-block`, you just need to put `text-align: center;` on their parent element. In the future, please make sure the problem you're trying to solve is present in the question itself, without relying on external resources (like other sites/pages). If this resource were to ever go down, your question becomes all but useless to future readers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to center an inline-block element and if so, how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7601678/is-it-possible-to-center-an-inline-block-element-and-if-so-how)

Comment: You are using js composer plugin in your wordpress site. Simply you have the option to align the items to center in js composer. Edit column and there you will find it.

Comment: @TylerRoper, Sorry for this very late reply! Tried your advice, but, no luck. Many thanks buddy! Have a great day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kindly change your CSS from

```
.circle {
    width: 240px;
    height: 240px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #ea4335;
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

to this

```
.circle {
    width: 240px;
    height: 240px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #ea4335;
    vertical-align: top;
    display: block;
    padding-top: 10px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

And it will work perfectly fine. I just made these elements block give them an auto margin and give some top padding to the text.

Answer (score 0):

try following code for good design some change for good design please add one div for all content vertically center when you add one line code or more than large content set vertically center also your circle center in mobile.

```css
.circle {
  width: 240px;
  height: 240px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #ea4335;
  vertical-align: top; 
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.vertical-center {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.circle h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.circle p {
  margin: 0;
}
.circle:hover {
  background-color:#79c852;
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<div class="wpb_wrapper">
  <div class="circle">
    <div class="vertical-center">
      <h2 class="w-h2">
        <span style="color: #ffffff;">Step 3</span>
      </h2>
      <p>Run the&nbsp; popular Elite Edge training</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it works well without the 'vertical-center' for me. Both you and Shaharyar's solution are working. Many thanks.

Answer (score -1):

add the div before the circle class. like this and it will resolve the problem

```
<style>
.divCenter{margin:0 auto;text-align:center;}
</style>
    <div style="margin:0 auto;text-align:center;">
          <div class="circle"> 
             <h2><span style="color: #ffffff;">Step 1</span></h2> 
             <p>Tell us your team’s resilience and leadership goals</p>
          </div>
```

Comment: 4 wpb_wrapper used inline - separately. Found the solution from Dharmesh and Shaharyar. Thank you :)