# Center an inline-block element within a div

Tags: html, css

I have an inline-block element that must be centered within a div.

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="other">
    some stuff that should not be centered
  </div>
  <div class="other2">
    some stuff that should not be centered
  </div>
  <div class="element">
    some element that needs to be centered
  </div>
</div>
```

I only have access to the CSS and not the HTML. I cannot use "text-align: center" on the parent div, as there are a lot of containers within the parent. The element must remain an inline-block element.

I only want to center "element". How can I do this?

Comment: Can't you just `text-align: center` on the `.element` class?

Comment: Sorry, should have specified it was not text that needed to be centered. I am trying to center the whole "element" div, not text within it.

Comment: As you don't/can't use Flexbox, I changed the duplicate. Have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46590898/2827823 ... also note, you can use `position: relative` along with this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34071945/2827823

Answer (score -2):

[`text-align: center`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align) is indeed the way to go; it's merely a matter of finding a selector that will only target the element that you're after. Based on your above example, all you *should* need is `.element`:

```css
.element {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="other">
    some stuff that should not be centered
  </div>
  <div class="other2">
    some stuff that should not be centered
  </div>
  <div class="element">
    some stuff that needs to be centered
  </div>
</div>
```

Assuming there are multiple elements with the class `element` you can use the [child combinator selector (`>`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator) as `.parent > .element` to specifically target the one that is a direct child of `.parent`:

```css
.parent > .element {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="other">
    some stuff that should not be centered
  </div>
  <div class="other2">
    some stuff that should not be centered
  </div>
  <div class="element">
    some stuff that needs to be centered
  </div>
</div>
```

You could also use a pseudo-selector like [`:nth-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type) with `.parent > div:nth-of-type(3)`, which would target the third `<div>` child of `.parent`, and thus achieve the same result:

```css
.parent > div:nth-of-type(3) {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="other">
    some stuff that should not be centered
  </div>
  <div class="other2">
    some stuff that should not be centered
  </div>
  <div class="element">
    some stuff that needs to be centered
  </div>
</div>
```

If you're looking to center the whole element and not just the text, you're looking for [`margin: 0 auto`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin), though note that a `<div>` element occupies the full `width` of the line by default, so you'll want to set a `width` on the element as well. Ideally this would be `width: fit-content`, to ensure that the element only occupies as much space as the text:

```css
.parent > .element {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: fit-content;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="other">
    some stuff that should not be centered
  </div>
  <div class="other2">
    some stuff that should not be centered
  </div>
  <div class="element">
    some stuff that needs to be centered
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that `margin` only applies to block-level elements (which `<div>` is by default), so if you manually changed this with `display: inline-block` (or you're using a `<span>`), you'll need to additionally set `display: block`.

Comment: This seems to just center align the stuff inside "element". I am trying to center the whole div in regards to the parent.

Comment: Then you're looking for `margin: 0 auto` instead, though note that you'll need to give it a fixed `width`. I'll update my answer to mention that.

Comment: You'd also need to set `display:block`, otherwise `margin:0 auto` wouldn't work.

Comment: @jdfink - A `<div>` element is block-level by default, though I'll specify that as well.

Comment: @ObsidianAge I only mention that because the OP says it's an inline-block element that needs to be centered. You're 100% right, just pointing it out for the OP.